# normal-erase-is-backspace-mode does not work over ssh when included in .emacs

Tags: minor-mode, terminal-emacs

In my `.emacs` file I have the following line:

```
(normal-erase-is-backspace-mode)
```

to change `<backspace>` to backwards delete and `^H` to help over the terminal. Unfortunately when I use emacs with `-nw` over ssh, this mode is not applied. When I run `M-x normal-erase-is-backspace-mode RET` after emacs is loaded, the mode is applied.

Is there a way to make `normal-erase-is-backspace-mode` work as expected (e.g. by executing `(normal-erase-is-backspace-mode)` after loading emacs)?

My Emacs version 23.1.1

Comment: Is that the only setting from your `.emacs` that is not being applied? I wonder if it is not reading your `.emacs` at all.

Comment: Other settings are applied fine (such as hooks for opening files).

Comment: From the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/DEL-Does-Not-Delete.html), `normal-erase-is-backspace-mode` simply toggles the state. So may be your terminal session is starting with the correct state? And then you are toggling again manually to make it right? See if commenting that line helps. Also with this setting commented out, can you tell which of the 3 anomalies (listed in the above documentation link) is that you are seeing?

Comment: Adding to what @kaushalmodi said, you can always run stuff "after emacs is loaded" by doing `(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook (lambda () (normal-erase-is-backspace-mode +1)))`.

Comment: @NathanaelFarley Was this issue resolved?

Comment: Apologies I haven't had a chance to test this yet! Will do tomorrow morning.

Comment: Apologies, emacs is working fine now without any need for `normal-erase-is-backspace-mode`. I'm not sure what the problem was before! I suggest closing as not relevant.